# Unable to add a VIRTUAL display to Xorg

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xrandr, proprietary-drivers

I've been trying to set up a virtual display with Xorg, but there's just no virtual display in `xrandr`.

This seems to be totally ignored:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Device1"
        Driver     "intel"
        Option     "VirtualHeads" "1" 
EndSection
```

**Specs:**

- OS: Debian Testing (Bullseye)
- Nvidia proprietary driver version: 440.82
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz

[lspci](https://pastebin.com/C1DAyh15)

[xrandr --verbose](https://pastebin.com/D9eR8cLA)

[xorg.log](https://pastebin.com/DQ9kyMru)

[xorg.conf](https://pastebin.com/MC7Wp72U)

I've also tried adding this to the `xorg.conf` with no success (I've tried `Device1` as well):

```
Section "Screen"
     Identifier      "VirtualScreen0"
     Device          "Device0"
     SubSection "Display"
            Virtual         1600 900
     EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Why:** I want to use my laptop as a second display using VNC.

I've spent half of a day trying to figure this out, but with no success. I feel like I've tried everything. Does anyone have any clue how to get this working?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Device` section with `VirtualHeads` is being ignored because you do not have an Intel card (your `xorg.log` indicates you have NVidia). Unfortunately the `nvidia` driver doesn't support virtual screens (the `modesetting` driver that's recommended for intel cards nowadays doesn't support it either, btw), and it's not possible to use the `dummy` driver without breaking `xrandr` in the process (you'd need to have a static "xinerama" configuration in `xorg.conf` and that's not something you want to do in 2020).

Fortunately it's possible to (ab)use the [DisplayLink `evdi`](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi) kernel module to add virtual outputs to any Xorg driver that has the Source Output `xrandr` provider. The process is as follows:

1. Install `evdi`, either via `apt install evdi-dkms` or, if you get build errors because your kernel is too new, using [this make target](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/blob/adf6eabb2a8344bea10836f063b7e2d27cb1530d/module/Makefile#L84) from DisplayLink's git repo.
2. Load the kernel module:

   ```
   modprobe evdi initial_device_count=2
   ```

   You may then add

   ```
   options evdi initial_device_count=2
   ```

   to `/etc/modprobe.d/local-evdi.conf` to persist this across reboots.
3. Restart X, you should now see two additional Sink Output providers in `xrandr --listproviders`
4. Enable the new output:

   ```
   xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0 --setprovideroutputsource 2 0
   ```

   You'll need to do this whenever you restart X, so put it to some autostart or something.
5. Add the desired output resolution to the `xrandr` configuration

   ```
   xrandr --addmode DVI-I-1-1 1920x1080
   ```
6. Enable the new output:

   ```
   xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of HDMI-0
   ```

Now there's a second dummy screen to the right of your primary one and you can start a VNC server there. Hope it works for you! :-)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I've tried what you suggested and sadly nothing changed. The output of `xrandr --verbose` is still the same. This is my current [xorg.conf](https://paste.debian.net/1145441/) and this is my current [xorg.log](https://paste.debian.net/1145443/).

Comment: Oh, you're right, I just tried it myself and it's not as easy as I thought. I'll edit the answer with a working solution.

Comment: Edited my answer with an alternative solution that I actually tested and confirmed. Hope it works!

Comment: I've followed your instruction. When I run `xrandr --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of HDMI-0` my computer froze, at that moment I had to leave. I come back in an hour or so and the virtual display was there, but there were artefacts around the cursor. I decided to try to restart my PC to see if it persists. I run the command that froze my PC before and it happened again. I waited for 30 minutes and then surrendered. I SSHed into the PC from my Notebook and retrieved the [Xorg.log](https://paste.debian.net/1145533/). Any idea what could be the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh. :-( Unfortunately I don't have any further ideas. It's possible that it only works reliably with intel, or maybe it's something else entirely. I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all help anyway. I am going to mark your answer as correct, since it may solve the issue for other people :-)

Comment: @TomášJanoušek, the `Makefile` from the `evdi` repo has changed and the line you link to no longer shows a specific target. Can you name the target? Is it `install_dkms`?

Comment: @LeoRochael Yes, that one. I've fixed the link in the answer (in a way that it never breaks again). Thanks for catching this!

Comment: For me, my DVI-I-2-1 stays disconnected and I can't use it as virtual monitor. How do I tell X/xrandr to see it as connected?

Comment: I just found out that I can mirror the new virtual monitor, but I can't change it's resolution because it doesn't find the mode `xrandr: cannot find mode 1280x800` even though I added it with `xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2-1 1280x800`